# Composer\Downloader\TransportException by composer.phar self-update in a Zend Framework 2 application

Tags: php, zend-framework2, composer-php

I'm trying to update the Zend Framework 2 library in a project and get an exception:

```
use@machine:/path/to/project# php composer.phar self-update
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                       
The "https://getcomposer.org/version" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway)
```

Also tried it [so](http://docs.behat.org/quick_intro.html), but the error is still there:

```
use@machine:/path/to/project# curl http://getcomposer.org/installer | php
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   166  100   166    0     0   1490      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  4611
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: I'd say their server's having a 'moment' -> http://getcomposer.org

Comment: Hm... I've just tried it with `ping getcomposer.org`. The server is sending responses: `4 packages sent, 4 packages received, 0 packages lost`...

Comment: Yes, the server's responding, but some other issue is preventing it serving the page requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The composer server is currently down

Answer (score 0):

One of the servers that host a library composer is trying to download for the application you are installing didn't serve up a needed file, and composer died with an error message.  Wait "a little bit" and try the create-project command again.